# Android maps not shown after the updating the production version. Only map tiles are shown?

Tags: android

The maps are showing only tiled view. Maps are not visible after publishing the updated version.

the following are the details of the Manifest file versioning changes while posting to the production.

When i have published the version for production for the first time with

```
versionCode = "1"
versionName = "1.0"
```

the maps are working fine.

But, When i am updated the production version recently with the same `keystore` the app is not showing the maps.

```
versionCode = "2"
versionName = "1.1"
```

While I am trying to debug the app i have got the following error report:

```
04-10 02:55:24.935: W/System.err(8509): IOException processing: 26
04-10 02:55:24.935: W/System.err(8509): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
04-10 02:55:24.940: W/System.err(8509):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
04-10 02:55:24.940: W/System.err(8509):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
04-10 02:55:24.940: W/System.err(8509):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
04-10 02:55:24.945: W/System.err(8509):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
04-10 02:55:24.945: W/System.err(8509):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
04-10 02:55:24.945: W/System.err(8509):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default api key?

Get the API key using your certificate.

Comment: I tried to get the api key for my certificate. But, unfortunately i am unable to get the api key here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

is there a way any ..? please, let me know ..

Comment: i have released 1.1 version for production recently where the maps are not working, while 1.0 version was working without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE TRY:

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


       outside<application></application>
```

- Copy your release key somewhere Change the keystore password/key
- password and key alias following the instructions here Change
  Eclipse's Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom keystore setting 
  to the path of the file in step 1.

Done!

Comment: I hope all the permission have to be given outside the application tag only without which its not a valid. i have given it still this doesn't works. i think problem is else where.?

Answer (score 0):

lavan. There are a number of permissions and other components that are required, and I assume that changing the version will also affect whether the application conforms to the list that you create at Google when you create the API project that this permission relies upon.

For example....the key generated in the .apk file will not change, but...if you changed the package name, you will have to add that to the API Project at Google. I have three packages that are all signed with the same debug key and use the same API key. You append the qualified package name to the end of your SHA-1 key to enable that package to use the same API key.

Here is what my manifest looks like, less the specifics for my app....I am using a MapFragment and not a MapView....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                  android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="your.package.name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                   android:value="your API KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```